# How to use native token as fee in CCIP local unit tests?

Tags: testing, chainlink, foundry, ccip

Setting up unit tests for CCIP with the LINK token as the fee token is successful, but how can the same thing be done using native tokens such as ETH as the fee token?

For example, here is part of the successful Foundry test setUp using `linkAddress` as the fee token:

```
EVM2EVMOnRampSetup.setUp();
        EVM2EVMOnRamp.FeeTokenConfigArgs[] memory feeTokenConfigArgs = new EVM2EVMOnRamp.FeeTokenConfigArgs[](1);
        feeTokenConfigArgs[0] = EVM2EVMOnRamp.FeeTokenConfigArgs({
            token: linkAddress,
            networkFeeUSDCents: 10,
            gasMultiplierWeiPerEth: 1e9,
            premiumMultiplierWeiPerEth: 1e9,
            enabled: true
        });
        EVM2EVMOnRamp onRamp = new EVM2EVMOnRamp(
            EVM2EVMOnRamp.StaticConfig({
                linkToken: linkAddress,
                chainSelector: SOURCE_CHAIN_ID,
                destChainSelector: SEPOLIA_CHAIN_SELECTOR,
                defaultTxGasLimit: GAS_LIMIT,
                maxNopFeesJuels: MAX_NOP_FEES_JUELS,
                prevOnRamp: address(0),
                armProxy: address(mockArmAddress)
            }),
            generateDynamicOnRampConfig(address(router), address(s_priceRegistry)),
            getTokensAndPools(s_sourceTokens, getCastedSourcePools()),
            rateLimiterConfig(),
            feeTokenConfigArgs,
            s_tokenTransferFeeConfigArgs,
            getNopsAndWeights()
        );
        onRampAddress = address(onRamp);

        Internal.TokenPriceUpdate[] memory tokenPriceUpdates = new Internal.TokenPriceUpdate[](1);
        tokenPriceUpdates[0] = Internal.TokenPriceUpdate({sourceToken: linkAddress, usdPerToken: 10000000000000000000});
        Internal.GasPriceUpdate[] memory gasPriceUpdates = new Internal.GasPriceUpdate[](1);
        gasPriceUpdates[0] =
            Internal.GasPriceUpdate({destChainSelector: SEPOLIA_CHAIN_SELECTOR, usdPerUnitGas: 500000000000000});
        Internal.PriceUpdates memory priceUpdates =
            Internal.PriceUpdates({tokenPriceUpdates: tokenPriceUpdates, gasPriceUpdates: gasPriceUpdates});
        IPriceRegistry(address(s_priceRegistry)).updatePrices(priceUpdates);
```

This works fine, but how can this work with the native token in place of `linkAddress`?

Thanks!

***Edit***: Here is the full test setUp with `address(0)` in place of `linkAddress`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.19;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {DeployBurnAndSend} from "../../script/DeployBurnAndSend.s.sol";
import {BurnAndSend} from "../../src/BurnAndSend.sol";
import {HelperBaSConfig} from "../../script/HelperBaSConfig.s.sol";
import {ReceiveAndReimburse} from "../../src/ReceiveAndReimburse.sol";
import {MockToken} from "../mocks/MockToken.sol";
import {BurnContract} from "../../src/BurnContract.sol";
import {Vm} from "forge-std/Vm.sol";
import {Client} from "@chainlink/contracts-ccip/src/v0.8/ccip/libraries/Client.sol";
import {Router} from "@chainlink/contracts-ccip/src/v0.8/ccip/Router.sol";
import {EVM2EVMOnRamp} from "@chainlink/contracts-ccip/src/v0.8/ccip/onRamp/EVM2EVMOnRamp.sol";
import {EVM2EVMOnRampSetup} from "@chainlink/contracts-ccip/src/v0.8/ccip/test/onRamp/EVM2EVMOnRampSetup.t.sol";
import {MockARM} from "@chainlink/contracts-ccip/src/v0.8/ccip/test/mocks/MockARM.sol";
import {IPriceRegistry} from "@chainlink/contracts-ccip/src/v0.8/ccip/interfaces/IPriceRegistry.sol";
import {Internal} from "@chainlink/contracts-ccip/src/v0.8/ccip/libraries/Internal.sol";
import {IERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol";

contract TestBurnAndSend is Test, EVM2EVMOnRampSetup {
    BurnAndSend burnAndSend;
    ReceiveAndReimburse receiveAndReimburse;
    HelperBaSConfig helperConfig;
    Router router;
    MockToken token;
    MockARM mockArm;
    BurnContract burnContract;

    address tokenAddress;
    address receiveAndReimburseAddress;
    address burnContractAddress;
    address routerAddress;
    address onRampAddress;
    address mockArmAddress;
    address priceRegistryAddress;

    uint64 destinationChainSelector;

    address public owner = msg.sender;
    address public user = makeAddr("user");
    uint256 public constant TEN_ETHER = 10 ether;
    uint256 public constant ONE_HUNDRED_THOUSAND_TOKENS = 100_000 * 1e18;
    uint16 public constant MAX_RET_BYTES = 4 + 4 * 32;

    function setUp() public override {
        DeployBurnAndSend deployer = new DeployBurnAndSend();
        (burnAndSend, helperConfig) = deployer.run();
        (tokenAddress, receiveAndReimburseAddress, routerAddress, destinationChainSelector, mockArmAddress) =
            helperConfig.activeNetworkConfig();
        token = MockToken(tokenAddress);
        burnContract = BurnContract(burnContractAddress);
        router = Router(routerAddress);
        vm.deal(user, TEN_ETHER);

        EVM2EVMOnRampSetup.setUp();
        EVM2EVMOnRamp.FeeTokenConfigArgs[] memory feeTokenConfigArgs = new EVM2EVMOnRamp.FeeTokenConfigArgs[](1);
        feeTokenConfigArgs[0] = EVM2EVMOnRamp.FeeTokenConfigArgs({
            token: address(0),
            networkFeeUSDCents: 10,
            gasMultiplierWeiPerEth: 1e9,
            premiumMultiplierWeiPerEth: 1e9,
            enabled: true
        });
        EVM2EVMOnRamp onRamp = new EVM2EVMOnRamp(
            EVM2EVMOnRamp.StaticConfig({
                linkToken: address(0),
                chainSelector: SOURCE_CHAIN_ID,
                destChainSelector: destinationChainSelector,
                defaultTxGasLimit: GAS_LIMIT,
                maxNopFeesJuels: MAX_NOP_FEES_JUELS,
                prevOnRamp: address(0),
                armProxy: address(mockArmAddress)
            }),
            generateDynamicOnRampConfig(address(router), address(s_priceRegistry)),
            getTokensAndPools(s_sourceTokens, getCastedSourcePools()),
            rateLimiterConfig(),
            feeTokenConfigArgs,
            s_tokenTransferFeeConfigArgs,
            getNopsAndWeights()
        );
        onRampAddress = address(onRamp);

        Internal.TokenPriceUpdate[] memory tokenPriceUpdates = new Internal.TokenPriceUpdate[](1);
        tokenPriceUpdates[0] = Internal.TokenPriceUpdate({sourceToken: address(0), usdPerToken: 10000000000000000000});
        Internal.GasPriceUpdate[] memory gasPriceUpdates = new Internal.GasPriceUpdate[](1);
        gasPriceUpdates[0] =
            Internal.GasPriceUpdate({destChainSelector: destinationChainSelector, usdPerUnitGas: 500000000000000});
        Internal.PriceUpdates memory priceUpdates =
            Internal.PriceUpdates({tokenPriceUpdates: tokenPriceUpdates, gasPriceUpdates: gasPriceUpdates});
        IPriceRegistry(address(s_priceRegistry)).updatePrices(priceUpdates);
    }
}
```

Here are the logs when I run the test setUp with this:

```
Running 1 test for test/unit/TestBurnAndSend.t.sol:TestBurnAndSend
[FAIL. Reason: setup failed: custom error 35be3ac8:] setUp() (gas: 0)
Traces:
  [47077770] TestBurnAndSend::setUp()
    ├─ [9833339] → new DeployBurnAndSend@0x5615dEB798BB3E4dFa0139dFa1b3D433Cc23b72f
    │   └─ ← 48987 bytes of code
    ├─ [9419915] DeployBurnAndSend::run()
    │   ├─ [8789640] → new HelperBaSConfig@0x104fBc016F4bb334D775a19E8A6510109AC63E00
    │   │   ├─ [0] VM::startBroadcast()
    │   │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   │   ├─ [519048] → new MockToken@0x90193C961A926261B756D1E5bb255e67ff9498A1
    │   │   │   └─ ← 2367 bytes of code
    │   │   ├─ [468871] → new WETH9@0xA8452Ec99ce0C64f20701dB7dD3abDb607c00496
    │   │   │   └─ ← 2006 bytes of code
    │   │   ├─ [521965] → new MockARM@0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3
    │   │   │   └─ ← 2496 bytes of code
    │   │   ├─ [1847055] → new Router@0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76
    │   │   │   └─ ← 9002 bytes of code
    │   │   ├─ [621786] → new ReceiveAndReimburse@0x50EEf481cae4250d252Ae577A09bF514f224C6C4
    │   │   │   ├─ emit OwnershipTransferred(from: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, to: DefaultSender: [0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38])
    │   │   │   ├─ [24628] MockToken::approve(ReceiveAndReimburse: [0x50EEf481cae4250d252Ae577A09bF514f224C6C4], 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935 [1.157e77])
    │   │   │   │   ├─ emit Approval(owner: ReceiveAndReimburse: [0x50EEf481cae4250d252Ae577A09bF514f224C6C4], spender: ReceiveAndReimburse: [0x50EEf481cae4250d252Ae577A09bF514f224C6C4], value: 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935 [1.157e77])
    │   │   │   │   └─ ← true
    │   │   │   └─ ← 2859 bytes of code
    │   │   ├─ [0] VM::stopBroadcast()
    │   │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   │   └─ ← 22643 bytes of code
    │   ├─ [857] HelperBaSConfig::activeNetworkConfig() [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← MockToken: [0x90193C961A926261B756D1E5bb255e67ff9498A1], ReceiveAndReimburse: [0x50EEf481cae4250d252Ae577A09bF514f224C6C4], Router: [0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76], 16015286601757825753 [1.601e19], MockARM: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3]
    │   ├─ [0] VM::startBroadcast()
    │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   ├─ [550727] → new BurnAndSend@0x62c20Aa1e0272312BC100b4e23B4DC1Ed96dD7D1
    │   │   ├─ [12666] → new BurnContract@0x44c5C8E61e159198294fa08fF29B84297cA23A46
    │   │   │   └─ ← 63 bytes of code
    │   │   └─ ← 2522 bytes of code
    │   ├─ [0] VM::stopBroadcast()
    │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   └─ ← BurnAndSend: [0x62c20Aa1e0272312BC100b4e23B4DC1Ed96dD7D1], HelperBaSConfig: [0x104fBc016F4bb334D775a19E8A6510109AC63E00]
    ├─ [857] HelperBaSConfig::activeNetworkConfig() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← MockToken: [0x90193C961A926261B756D1E5bb255e67ff9498A1], ReceiveAndReimburse: [0x50EEf481cae4250d252Ae577A09bF514f224C6C4], Router: [0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76], 16015286601757825753 [1.601e19], MockARM: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3]
    ├─ [0] VM::deal(user: [0x6CA6d1e2D5347Bfab1d91e883F1915560e09129D], 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e)
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::deal(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e, 100000000000000000000 [1e20])
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] VM::warp(1234567890 [1.234e9])
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [521965] → new MockARM@0x899A409484421E84296c0D160C73935fc3248CFE
    │   └─ ← 2496 bytes of code
    ├─ [1278020] → new BurnMintERC677@0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F
    │   └─ ← 6041 bytes of code
    ├─ [2629] BurnMintERC677::balanceOf(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ [0] VM::record()
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [629] BurnMintERC677::balanceOf(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ [0] VM::accesses(BurnMintERC677: [0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F])
    │   └─ ← [0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc], []
    ├─ [0] VM::load(BurnMintERC677: [0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F], 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ├─ emit WARNING_UninitedSlot(who: BurnMintERC677: [0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F], slot: 764934884042868045814352046724595675337351549167798312178178738966062680540 [7.649e74])
    ├─ emit SlotFound(who: BurnMintERC677: [0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F], fsig: 0x70a0823100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, keysHash: 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc, slot: 764934884042868045814352046724595675337351549167798312178178738966062680540 [7.649e74])
    ├─ [629] BurnMintERC677::balanceOf(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ [0] VM::load(BurnMintERC677: [0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F], 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ├─ [0] VM::store(BurnMintERC677: [0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F], 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc, 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [1966054] → new LockReleaseTokenPool@0x28004B9164252A4B7B2a5bBBf65990F8b965f744
    │   └─ ← 9703 bytes of code
    ├─ [1278020] → new BurnMintERC677@0x8dB4F1d4411aF6942211d14FDAFa3Dbe55f997Dd
    │   └─ ← 6041 bytes of code
    ├─ [2629] BurnMintERC677::balanceOf(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ [0] VM::record()
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [629] BurnMintERC677::balanceOf(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ [0] VM::accesses(BurnMintERC677: [0x8dB4F1d4411aF6942211d14FDAFa3Dbe55f997Dd])
    │   └─ ← [0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc], []
    ├─ [0] VM::load(BurnMintERC677: [0x8dB4F1d4411aF6942211d14FDAFa3Dbe55f997Dd], 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ├─ emit WARNING_UninitedSlot(who: BurnMintERC677: [0x8dB4F1d4411aF6942211d14FDAFa3Dbe55f997Dd], slot: 764934884042868045814352046724595675337351549167798312178178738966062680540 [7.649e74])
    ├─ emit SlotFound(who: BurnMintERC677: [0x8dB4F1d4411aF6942211d14FDAFa3Dbe55f997Dd], fsig: 0x70a0823100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, keysHash: 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc, slot: 764934884042868045814352046724595675337351549167798312178178738966062680540 [7.649e74])
    ├─ [629] BurnMintERC677::balanceOf(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ [0] VM::load(BurnMintERC677: [0x8dB4F1d4411aF6942211d14FDAFa3Dbe55f997Dd], 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ├─ [0] VM::store(BurnMintERC677: [0x8dB4F1d4411aF6942211d14FDAFa3Dbe55f997Dd], 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc, 0x0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000)
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [1661143] → new BurnMintTokenPool@0xE55c1374bc6A38CEA4e86F3A7e5b1cF17dB54185
    │   └─ ← 8181 bytes of code
    ├─ [136676] BurnMintERC677::grantMintAndBurnRoles(BurnMintTokenPool: [0xE55c1374bc6A38CEA4e86F3A7e5b1cF17dB54185])
    │   ├─ emit MintAccessGranted(minter: BurnMintTokenPool: [0xE55c1374bc6A38CEA4e86F3A7e5b1cF17dB54185])
    │   ├─ emit BurnAccessGranted(burner: BurnMintTokenPool: [0xE55c1374bc6A38CEA4e86F3A7e5b1cF17dB54185])
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [1278020] → new BurnMintERC677@0xcE4ec7b524851E51d5C55eeFbBb8E58E8Ce2515F
    │   └─ ← 6041 bytes of code
    ├─ [2629] BurnMintERC677::balanceOf(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ [0] VM::record()
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [629] BurnMintERC677::balanceOf(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ [0] VM::accesses(BurnMintERC677: [0xcE4ec7b524851E51d5C55eeFbBb8E58E8Ce2515F])
    │   └─ ← [0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc], []
    ├─ [0] VM::load(BurnMintERC677: [0xcE4ec7b524851E51d5C55eeFbBb8E58E8Ce2515F], 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ├─ emit WARNING_UninitedSlot(who: BurnMintERC677: [0xcE4ec7b524851E51d5C55eeFbBb8E58E8Ce2515F], slot: 764934884042868045814352046724595675337351549167798312178178738966062680540 [7.649e74])
    ├─ emit SlotFound(who: BurnMintERC677: [0xcE4ec7b524851E51d5C55eeFbBb8E58E8Ce2515F], fsig: 0x70a0823100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, keysHash: 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc, slot: 764934884042868045814352046724595675337351549167798312178178738966062680540 [7.649e74])
    ├─ [629] BurnMintERC677::balanceOf(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ [0] VM::load(BurnMintERC677: [0xcE4ec7b524851E51d5C55eeFbBb8E58E8Ce2515F], 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ├─ [0] VM::store(BurnMintERC677: [0xcE4ec7b524851E51d5C55eeFbBb8E58E8Ce2515F], 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc, 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [1966054] → new LockReleaseTokenPool@0x9E7218A11a2CDA657AE50Bd9cC5F953174AaE2a5
    │   └─ ← 9703 bytes of code
    ├─ [1278020] → new BurnMintERC677@0x3c78e47de47B765dcEE2F30F31B3CF5F10B42d1F
    │   └─ ← 6041 bytes of code
    ├─ [2629] BurnMintERC677::balanceOf(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ [0] VM::record()
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [629] BurnMintERC677::balanceOf(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ [0] VM::accesses(BurnMintERC677: [0x3c78e47de47B765dcEE2F30F31B3CF5F10B42d1F])
    │   └─ ← [0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc], []
    ├─ [0] VM::load(BurnMintERC677: [0x3c78e47de47B765dcEE2F30F31B3CF5F10B42d1F], 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ├─ emit WARNING_UninitedSlot(who: BurnMintERC677: [0x3c78e47de47B765dcEE2F30F31B3CF5F10B42d1F], slot: 764934884042868045814352046724595675337351549167798312178178738966062680540 [7.649e74])
    ├─ emit SlotFound(who: BurnMintERC677: [0x3c78e47de47B765dcEE2F30F31B3CF5F10B42d1F], fsig: 0x70a0823100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, keysHash: 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc, slot: 764934884042868045814352046724595675337351549167798312178178738966062680540 [7.649e74])
    ├─ [629] BurnMintERC677::balanceOf(0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ [0] VM::load(BurnMintERC677: [0x3c78e47de47B765dcEE2F30F31B3CF5F10B42d1F], 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ├─ [0] VM::store(BurnMintERC677: [0x3c78e47de47B765dcEE2F30F31B3CF5F10B42d1F], 0x01b0f013c48622ded1db47eb5caa10e66419ff77b3adf8b23651364eb037c9dc, 0x0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000)
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [1892838] → new MaybeRevertingBurnMintTokenPool@0xe2C2bB2F43b91f65b5519708e340310394C72d8f
    │   └─ ← 9312 bytes of code
    ├─ [136676] BurnMintERC677::grantMintAndBurnRoles(MaybeRevertingBurnMintTokenPool: [0xe2C2bB2F43b91f65b5519708e340310394C72d8f])
    │   ├─ emit MintAccessGranted(minter: MaybeRevertingBurnMintTokenPool: [0xe2C2bB2F43b91f65b5519708e340310394C72d8f])
    │   ├─ emit BurnAccessGranted(burner: MaybeRevertingBurnMintTokenPool: [0xe2C2bB2F43b91f65b5519708e340310394C72d8f])
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [25108] BurnMintERC677::transfer(LockReleaseTokenPool: [0x9E7218A11a2CDA657AE50Bd9cC5F953174AaE2a5], 10000000000000000000000000 [1e25])
    │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e, to: LockReleaseTokenPool: [0x9E7218A11a2CDA657AE50Bd9cC5F953174AaE2a5], value: 10000000000000000000000000 [1e25])
    │   └─ ← true
    ├─ [468871] → new WETH9@0xE4EeBE19216Af86b9A996f53BD80b8365F832bE8
    │   └─ ← 2006 bytes of code
    ├─ [1847055] → new Router@0xEf9622d22c61Bb77cdd6605660400B9D4FB33548
    │   └─ ← 9002 bytes of code
    ├─ [468871] → new WETH9@0xbd2F7046d1059ABFE5316b48F050684a4676710f
    │   └─ ← 2006 bytes of code
    ├─ [1847055] → new Router@0xCA8FAd64b40a853Aeb1839b302406c77e3C9e878
    │   └─ ← 9002 bytes of code
    ├─ [397] Router::getWrappedNative() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← WETH9: [0xE4EeBE19216Af86b9A996f53BD80b8365F832bE8]
    ├─ [397] Router::getWrappedNative() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← WETH9: [0xE4EeBE19216Af86b9A996f53BD80b8365F832bE8]
    ├─ [397] Router::getWrappedNative() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← WETH9: [0xbd2F7046d1059ABFE5316b48F050684a4676710f]
    ├─ [1235752] → new PriceRegistry@0xc7Ef28AF215Ac060c10657C48f946d178c96d5a4
    │   ├─ emit FeeTokenAdded(feeToken: BurnMintERC677: [0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F])
    │   ├─ emit FeeTokenAdded(feeToken: WETH9: [0xE4EeBE19216Af86b9A996f53BD80b8365F832bE8])
    │   └─ ← 5481 bytes of code
    ├─ [175204] PriceRegistry::updatePrices(PriceUpdates({ tokenPriceUpdates: [TokenPriceUpdate({ sourceToken: 0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F, usdPerToken: 5000000000000000000 [5e18] }), TokenPriceUpdate({ sourceToken: 0x8dB4F1d4411aF6942211d14FDAFa3Dbe55f997Dd, usdPerToken: 2000000000000000000000 [2e21] }), TokenPriceUpdate({ sourceToken: 0xE4EeBE19216Af86b9A996f53BD80b8365F832bE8, usdPerToken: 2000000000000000000000 [2e21] }), TokenPriceUpdate({ sourceToken: 0xcE4ec7b524851E51d5C55eeFbBb8E58E8Ce2515F, usdPerToken: 5000000000000000000 [5e18] }), TokenPriceUpdate({ sourceToken: 0x3c78e47de47B765dcEE2F30F31B3CF5F10B42d1F, usdPerToken: 2000000000000000000000 [2e21] }), TokenPriceUpdate({ sourceToken: 0xbd2F7046d1059ABFE5316b48F050684a4676710f, usdPerToken: 2000000000000000000000 [2e21] })], gasPriceUpdates: [GasPriceUpdate({ destChainSelector: 2, usdPerUnitGas: 5192296858534827628530496329220096001000000 [5.192e42] })] }))
    │   ├─ emit UsdPerTokenUpdated(token: BurnMintERC677: [0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F], value: 5000000000000000000 [5e18], timestamp: 1234567890 [1.234e9])
    │   ├─ emit UsdPerTokenUpdated(token: BurnMintERC677: [0x8dB4F1d4411aF6942211d14FDAFa3Dbe55f997Dd], value: 2000000000000000000000 [2e21], timestamp: 1234567890 [1.234e9])
    │   ├─ emit UsdPerTokenUpdated(token: WETH9: [0xE4EeBE19216Af86b9A996f53BD80b8365F832bE8], value: 2000000000000000000000 [2e21], timestamp: 1234567890 [1.234e9])
    │   ├─ emit UsdPerTokenUpdated(token: BurnMintERC677: [0xcE4ec7b524851E51d5C55eeFbBb8E58E8Ce2515F], value: 5000000000000000000 [5e18], timestamp: 1234567890 [1.234e9])
    │   ├─ emit UsdPerTokenUpdated(token: BurnMintERC677: [0x3c78e47de47B765dcEE2F30F31B3CF5F10B42d1F], value: 2000000000000000000000 [2e21], timestamp: 1234567890 [1.234e9])
    │   ├─ emit UsdPerTokenUpdated(token: WETH9: [0xbd2F7046d1059ABFE5316b48F050684a4676710f], value: 2000000000000000000000 [2e21], timestamp: 1234567890 [1.234e9])
    │   ├─ emit UsdPerUnitGasUpdated(destChain: 2, value: 5192296858534827628530496329220096001000000 [5.192e42], timestamp: 1234567890 [1.234e9])
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [25922] PriceRegistry::updatePrices(PriceUpdates({ tokenPriceUpdates: [TokenPriceUpdate({ sourceToken: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000003039, usdPerToken: 100000000000000000 [1e17] })], gasPriceUpdates: [] }))
    │   ├─ emit UsdPerTokenUpdated(token: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000003039, value: 100000000000000000 [1e17], timestamp: 1234567890 [1.234e9])
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [397] Router::getWrappedNative() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← WETH9: [0xE4EeBE19216Af86b9A996f53BD80b8365F832bE8]
    ├─ [397] Router::getWrappedNative() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← WETH9: [0xE4EeBE19216Af86b9A996f53BD80b8365F832bE8]
    ├─ [4956339] → new EVM2EVMOnRampHelper@0x912cF1EE1d4a3A302DfC64d70Bd023e6839A5dD8
    │   ├─ emit ConfigSet(staticConfig: StaticConfig({ linkToken: 0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F, chainSelector: 1, destChainSelector: 2, defaultTxGasLimit: 200000 [2e5], maxNopFeesJuels: 1000000000000000000000000000 [1e27], prevOnRamp: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, armProxy: 0x899A409484421E84296c0D160C73935fc3248CFE }), dynamicConfig: DynamicConfig({ router: 0xEf9622d22c61Bb77cdd6605660400B9D4FB33548, maxNumberOfTokensPerMsg: 5, destGasOverhead: 350000 [3.5e5], destGasPerPayloadByte: 16, destDataAvailabilityOverheadGas: 33596 [3.359e4], destGasPerDataAvailabilityByte: 16, destDataAvailabilityMultiplierBps: 6840, priceRegistry: 0xc7Ef28AF215Ac060c10657C48f946d178c96d5a4, maxDataBytes: 30000 [3e4], maxPerMsgGasLimit: 4000000 [4e6] }))
    │   ├─ emit FeeConfigSet(feeConfig: [FeeTokenConfigArgs({ token: 0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F, networkFeeUSDCents: 100, gasMultiplierWeiPerEth: 1000000000000000000 [1e18], premiumMultiplierWeiPerEth: 500000000000000000 [5e17], enabled: true }), FeeTokenConfigArgs({ token: 0xE4EeBE19216Af86b9A996f53BD80b8365F832bE8, networkFeeUSDCents: 500, gasMultiplierWeiPerEth: 2000000000000000000 [2e18], premiumMultiplierWeiPerEth: 2000000000000000000 [2e18], enabled: true })])
    │   ├─ emit TokenTransferFeeConfigSet(transferFeeConfig: [TokenTransferFeeConfigArgs({ token: 0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F, minFeeUSDCents: 100, maxFeeUSDCents: 100000 [1e5], deciBps: 25, destGasOverhead: 40000 [4e4], destBytesOverhead: 0 }), TokenTransferFeeConfigArgs({ token: 0xE4EeBE19216Af86b9A996f53BD80b8365F832bE8, minFeeUSDCents: 50, maxFeeUSDCents: 50000 [5e4], deciBps: 50, destGasOverhead: 10000 [1e4], destBytesOverhead: 100 }), TokenTransferFeeConfigArgs({ token: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000003039, minFeeUSDCents: 200, maxFeeUSDCents: 200000 [2e5], deciBps: 100, destGasOverhead: 1, destBytesOverhead: 200 })])
    │   ├─ emit NopsSet(nopWeightsTotal: 72227 [7.222e4], nopsAndWeights: [NopAndWeight({ nop: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001, weight: 19284 [1.928e4] }), NopAndWeight({ nop: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002, weight: 52935 [5.293e4] }), NopAndWeight({ nop: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003, weight: 8 })])
    │   ├─ [314] LockReleaseTokenPool::getToken() [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← BurnMintERC677: [0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F]
    │   ├─ emit PoolAdded(token: BurnMintERC677: [0x2aC28C3aCB6B5d17AC8724c35f45434fD6Ff3E7F], pool: LockReleaseTokenPool: [0x28004B9164252A4B7B2a5bBBf65990F8b965f744])
    │   ├─ [292] BurnMintTokenPool::getToken() [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← BurnMintERC677: [0x8dB4F1d4411aF6942211d14FDAFa3Dbe55f997Dd]
    │   ├─ emit PoolAdded(token: BurnMintERC677: [0x8dB4F1d4411aF6942211d14FDAFa3Dbe55f997Dd], pool: BurnMintTokenPool: [0xE55c1374bc6A38CEA4e86F3A7e5b1cF17dB54185])
    │   └─ ← 21407 bytes of code
    ├─ [23752] EVM2EVMOnRampHelper::setAdmin(0x11118e64e1FB0c487f25dD6D3601FF6aF8d32E4e)
    │   ├─ emit AdminSet(newAdmin: 0x11118e64e1FB0c487f25dD6D3601FF6aF8d32E4e)
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [115858] LockReleaseTokenPool::applyRampUpdates([RampUpdate({ ramp: 0x912cF1EE1d4a3A302DfC64d70Bd023e6839A5dD8, allowed: true, rateLimiterConfig: Config({ isEnabled: true, capacity: 1000000000000000000000000000000 [1e30], rate: 1000000000000000 [1e15] }) })], [])
    │   ├─ emit OnRampAdded(onRamp: EVM2EVMOnRampHelper: [0x912cF1EE1d4a3A302DfC64d70Bd023e6839A5dD8], rateLimiterConfig: Config({ isEnabled: true, capacity: 1000000000000000000000000000000 [1e30], rate: 1000000000000000 [1e15] }))
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [115835] BurnMintTokenPool::applyRampUpdates([RampUpdate({ ramp: 0x912cF1EE1d4a3A302DfC64d70Bd023e6839A5dD8, allowed: true, rateLimiterConfig: Config({ isEnabled: true, capacity: 1000000000000000000000000000000 [1e30], rate: 1000000000000000 [1e15] }) })], [])
    │   ├─ emit OnRampAdded(onRamp: EVM2EVMOnRampHelper: [0x912cF1EE1d4a3A302DfC64d70Bd023e6839A5dD8], rateLimiterConfig: Config({ isEnabled: true, capacity: 1000000000000000000000000000000 [1e30], rate: 1000000000000000 [1e15] }))
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [141643] Router::applyRampUpdates([OnRamp({ destChainSelector: 2, onRamp: 0x912cF1EE1d4a3A302DfC64d70Bd023e6839A5dD8 })], [], [OffRamp({ sourceChainSelector: 1, offRamp: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000A }), OffRamp({ sourceChainSelector: 1, offRamp: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000b })])
    │   ├─ emit OnRampSet(destChainSelector: 2, onRamp: EVM2EVMOnRampHelper: [0x912cF1EE1d4a3A302DfC64d70Bd023e6839A5dD8])
    │   ├─ emit OffRampAdded(sourceChainSelector: 1, offRamp: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000A)
    │   ├─ emit OffRampAdded(sourceChainSelector: 1, offRamp: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000b)
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [24765] BurnMintERC677::approve(Router: [0xEf9622d22c61Bb77cdd6605660400B9D4FB33548], 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 [3.402e38])
    │   ├─ emit Approval(owner: 0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e, spender: Router: [0xEf9622d22c61Bb77cdd6605660400B9D4FB33548], value: 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 [3.402e38])
    │   └─ ← true
    ├─ [24765] BurnMintERC677::approve(Router: [0xEf9622d22c61Bb77cdd6605660400B9D4FB33548], 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 [3.402e38])
    │   ├─ emit Approval(owner: 0x00007e64E1fB0C487F25dd6D3601ff6aF8d32e4e, spender: Router: [0xEf9622d22c61Bb77cdd6605660400B9D4FB33548], value: 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 [3.402e38])
    │   └─ ← true
    ├─ [76762] → new <unknown>@0xDfb183BC8546E7f649292ffCa34b8DBD058DB4F7
    │   └─ ← 0 bytes of code
    └─ ← InvalidConfig()

Test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 6.32ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCIP converts native fees to a wrapped equivalent.

Add this import to the top of the test suite:

```
import {WETH9} from "@chainlink/contracts-ccip/src/v0.8/ccip/test/WETH9.sol";
```

Add this line to the setUp:

```
WETH9 weth9 = new WETH9();
```

Update `feeTokenConfigArgs` to use `address(weth9)` in place of the `token`:

```
EVM2EVMOnRamp.FeeTokenConfigArgs[] memory feeTokenConfigArgs = new EVM2EVMOnRamp.FeeTokenConfigArgs[](1);
        feeTokenConfigArgs[0] = EVM2EVMOnRamp.FeeTokenConfigArgs({
            token: address(weth9),
            networkFeeUSDCents: 10,
            gasMultiplierWeiPerEth: 1e9,
            premiumMultiplierWeiPerEth: 1e9,
            enabled: true
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use native tokens using address(0) instead of the LINK token address.

See the `transferTokensPayNative` function in this tutorial: https://docs.chain.link/ccip/tutorials/cross-chain-tokens#tutorial

Relevant code snippet:

```
        // Create an EVM2AnyMessage struct in memory with necessary information for sending a cross-chain message
        // address(0) means fees are paid in native gas
        Client.EVM2AnyMessage memory evm2AnyMessage = _buildCCIPMessage(
            _receiver,
            _token,
            _amount,
            address(0)
        );
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried that and get an `InvalidConfig()` error when trying to run the test suite. Please see edited post above for more context.

Comment: Ah, sorry, we are looking into this issue. We'll get back to you as soon as we have more information.

Comment: It works with the native token's wrapped equivalent - `address(weth9)` when setting up the `EVM2EVMOnRamp.FeeTokenConfigArgs`